# wrong location in respond_with multiple object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-with

I have to pass 2 objects to show so I tried to put this

```
respond_with(@ticketnfr, @ticket)
```

but it goes to ticket controller view,

when I tried with only one object

```
respond_with(@ticketnfr)
```

it goes correctly to ticketnfr/show, but I miss the ticket params,

I also tried to put the location

```
respond_with(@ticketnfr, @ticket. :location => ticketnfr_path)
```

but it goes to the index instead of show

how to pass both of the objects but still going to the ticketnfr/show?

Comment: Please, show you route for ticketnfr_path from routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@response = {:ticket => @ticket, :ticketnfr => @ticketnfr}
respond_with(@response)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, i have tried this but it is not working, i have an answer i will post it

Comment: current one should work, just wrap your objects and to have less code

Answer (score 0):

i have create the respond_with like this

```html
respond_with(@ticketnfr, :location => ticketnfr_url(:id => @ticketnfr.id, :ticket_id => @ticket.id))
```

Thank You